# Hibernate Inheritance: Load all entities but no subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance

Given two classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class A{
...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B extends A{
...
}
```

When calling

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = ...;
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.createCriteria(A.class).list()
```

I receive all instances of A **and** B.

How do I query for only instances of A (no subclasses of A)?

Comment: do you have a descriminator value in your table B ??

Comment: No, not yet. How would it resolve the issue?